# Mongoose .stream doesn't have populated fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, populate

I have a schema "Reports" that looks like this:

```
    var Reports = new Schema(
  {
    identifiersub: {            // Id of reported submission, populate stuff
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Submission"
    },
    identifiercom: {            // Id of reported comment, populate stuff
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Comments"
    },
    identifieruse: {            // Id of reported user, populate stuff
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "AccountDetails"
    },
    solved: {                   // Whether this problem has been solved or not
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    processed: [{               // Array of moderators who were participating in processing this report
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "AccountDetails"
    }],
    type: String,               // Type of content. bug, user, submission or comment
    reports: [                  // Additional text for each type of reported content
      {
        description: String,    // Text from select component. For bugs: the feature that is affected,
        reason: String,         // Reason for this report
        by: {                   // Reporter
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "AccountDetails"
        }
      }
    ],
    notes: [{                   // Admin notes
      title: String,            // Fleshed out discussion/reasoning
      note: String,             // Decided outcome that each note represents
      outcome: String,          // ("Keep reported", "delete", etc)
      date: Date,               // Date this note was added
      moderator: {              // Moderator who added this note
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "AccountDetails"
      }
    }]
  },
  { strict: false, timestamps: true }
)
```

And in my admin panel I want to implement a search function that searches all reports with the specified keyword. The most important field here is reports: it's an array of objects containing a "by" field which is an ObjectId. Now I wanted to populate the username for this id, but I'm not seeing it in my document...I use the .stream method to check the whole document including nested objects and arrays of objects. Here's my query:

```
  var cursor = Reports
  .find({ type: req.query.type})
  .limit(500)
  .populate("notes.moderator reports.by processed", "username")
  .populate("identifieruse", "username dob email ipaddress")
  .populate("identifiercom", "by.username comment")
  .populate("identifiersub", "meta.title by deleted")
  .sort("-createdAt")
  .lean()
  .stream();

  cursor.on('data', function(doc) {
    console.log(doc);
    if (doc.toString().includes(key)) results.push(doc)
  })
  cursor.on('error', function(err) {
    return catcherror(new Error(err), res)
  })
  cursor.on('close', function() {
    console.log(results);
    return res.send(results)
  })
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: you can use `$lookup` aggregation here...

Comment: So if I understand it correctly (according to the docs) will it attach the fields I select with the $lookup before it enters the stream/cursor?

Comment: yes it will do all for you within a pipeline and will not use cursor to reduce query execution time

Comment: Great! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use `.cursor()` instead of `.stream()` and it works.